# Grafana Tables: Cannot align data in same column

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am trying to show metrics like PID, memory usage, CPU usage for selected processes(nginx,php-fpm,mysql,redis) using node_exporter(Prometheus) in a tabular form. In order to achieve that, I added textfile with data coming from bash script. I was successfully able to send data through Prometheus but now I cant align the data in table accordingly.
Queries are as follows:

```
node_systemd_unit_pid{Service=“Nginx”}
node_systemd_unit_mem{Service=“Nginx”}
node_systemd_unit_cpu{Service=“Nginx”}
node_systemd_unit_pid{Service=“Mysql”}
…
and so on
```

On applying Outer join and Organize field transform I get the following results:

[image: Outer join and Organize field Result]

I have added headings from Organize filed transform:

[image: Organize field layout]

How can I have all the values in a tabular form under respected fields like all PID’s should be under PID column and so on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the columns don't align is that they are considered different value even if you set the same column name.

The correct expression is to request all processes in the same expression, to fill a column/Value:

```
node_systemd_mem{Service=~"Nginx|Mysql"}
```

Then you can rename `Value #X` into `Memory`.

IMHO, a good practice is to put the filter part (ex: `Nginx|Mysql`) into a hidden variable that you use in your expressions. It avoids repeating the same expression in all requests
and the day you want to change it, it is much easier.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Cant tell you how happy I am after you solved my problem. I had been searching for the solution from weeks. Thanks again for guiding me and putting me on the right track.